# How does one know that a given equation is 'scalar' equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, terminology, definition, constrained-dynamics

Here I post few lines from Rana and Joag *classical mechanics* page 40
The general velocity-dependent constraint is given by relation
$g(r,\dot{r},t) =0$. Then says this equation is a single [scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar) equation. But I am surprised if it depends on velocity then how is this scalar equation?

Comment: Dot product of two vectors is always a scalar.

Comment: Normally, vectors are identified in some fashion.  Frequently with bold type or little arrows on top.  What is the significance of the dot following your second r?

Comment: What does the author then do with the fact that it's a "single scalar equation"? That could help figure out what they mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The note that this is a single scalar equation is probably intended to clarify that the $0$ on the right hand side is a scalar, and not, for example, the zero vector $\vec 0$. So the function $g$ on the left hand side is a scalar function of $\vec r$, $\dot {\vec r}$ and $t$.

A simple example would be a particle that is constrained to move in a circle centred on the origin, in which case

$\vec r . \dot {\vec r} = 0$